# set vs unordered set! Which is better to use?

Tags: c++, data-structures, c++14

I have to find the number of unique elements in a list of n elements.
I have used set and it was accepted, but when i used unordered_set in one of the case time limit exceeded.How is it possible?

Code using set

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);
set<int> s;
int n;
cin >> n;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
int x;
cin >> x;
s.insert(x);
}
cout << s.size() << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

Code using Unordered_set

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
 ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
 cin.tie(NULL);
 unordered_set<int> s;
 int n;
 cin >> n;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
 int x;
 cin >> x;
 s.insert(x);
 }
 cout << s.size() << "\n";
 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

`set` uses a red black tree internally so  it   does operations internally just like a `BST`,  and  it   makes   a   `balanced tree`   so   searching   is approximately   `logarithmic time`   for   sure   in   any case,   but insertion   into  an `unordered_set`   depends   on   the   data   being   used   and the "internal hash function"    that   actually   determines   the   number   of   collisions  in   the   hash set,   so   it   may be   possible that due to a higher number of collisions due to a particular input, it may fail to handle the large number of collisions because collision handling also takes time because it may employ any of the 2 standard methods

Answer (score 0):

The test case contains values that hash very badly, with many collisions.
The worst-case complexity for insertion in `unordered_set` is linear in the size of the set.
Insertion in a `set` is logarithmic in the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

unordered_set insert() operation has worst case time complexity of O(n), while in case of ordered_set, time complexity is O(log(n)) as it maintain self balancing BST after each operation.
I recommend you to go through below documentation by CPP-reference and you can find all information releted to c++.

References:
For unordered_set:insert()

(1)https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert

For ordered_set:insert()

(2)https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert

Hope this helps..
happy codding..